# SOCRATA SODA query for array item (SELECT & GROUP BY)

Tags: sql, socrata, soda

Is it possible to select or group by an item within an array using SoQL?

For example, here is an item returned by the SODA API:

```
{
  "business_name" : "ACME CO",
  "phone_number" : {
      "phone_number" : "2145551234"
  },
  "zip_code" : "75235"
}
```

I would like to group by the phone number, but can't find a way to support it.  The phone number is not available as a non-array object, and the site does not support adding it to the group by via its GUI.

Trying something like the following causes an error stating all GROUP BY arguments must be column names:

```
$select=hospital_name%2Cphone_number&$group=hospital_name%2Cphone_number.phone_numer
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What dataset and API endpoint are you using? It looks like you're using a legacy 2.0 version API - in the 2.1 endpoint they'll be represented as text fields instead of objects and you should be able to aggregate on them.

Comment: The API doesn't seem to specify the version, and I can't find a means of contacting them.  data.medicare.gov is the endpoint.

Comment: Can you please provide the API endpoint you're using then? data.medicare.gov has many datasets with many APIs.